# Auto hide and unhide rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names on worksheet1 and some names has information and some don't and the information does carry over from another sheet. worksheet2 does not have a full list of names. I would like to auto hide rows on worksheet1 that does not contain information for the certain name. Once I have add the name on worksheet2 and the information I would like worksheet1 to unhided that name.

WorkSheet1 Full List of names are A7:A500
WorkSheet2 Partial List of names are E2:A100 ( I know the range will have to be change for worksheet1 to be able to match names if its possible.)

Is there a formula or use Macros to match the names to hide and unhide the rows?

I was going to use filter but then I have to remember that I had uncheck that name so I dont duplicate the same info.

I had tried to use filter to uncheck that name in worksheet1, but then I have to remeber to recheck once I have entered information on worksheet2.

Comment: it would be best to post a pic of your data structure in worksheet 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

In this example two sheets are used with names Base and Partial.

On Partial sheet  in ColumnA there are the items and in ColumnB write the info of the item.
So Partial sheet ColumnA and ColumnB

| No | ColumnA | ColumnB |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Items | P/N |  |
| 2 | pear | 25 |  |
| 3 | peach |  |  |
| 4 | apple | 623 |  |

On Base sheet leave four empty lines before the list in ColumnA.

| No | ColumnA | ColumnB |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | item | P/N |  |
| 6 | apple | =VLOOKUP(A5,Partial!A:B,2,FALSE) |  |
| 7 | apple |  |  |
| 8 | peach |  |  |
| 9 | grape |  |  |
| 10 | peach |  |  |
| 11 | pear |  |  |

Copy B6 cell down in the column as long it needed. The result will either the P/N from Partial sheet of the item, or #N/A if the item has no P/N value(like peach).
Apply Advanced Filter on Base sheet on the range you want to filter, with the parameters:

- Filter the list, in place
- List range: Select the requested range on Base ColumnA:ColumnB (e.g. $A$5:$B$12)
- Criteria range: Base!$A$2:$A$3

In cell Base sheet A3 type =IF(ISNA(B6),-1,B6)>0

Execute the filter with OK.

This works if instead of numbers on Partial sheet for P/N text is applied.